# from where i can import Boolean in ionic 4 /Angular 8

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, ionic4

```
Can't resolve all parameters for Tab1Page in /Users/apple/Desktop/Adhyatmavani/src/app/tab1/tab1.page.ts: ([object Object], ?).
```

**tab1.page.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: "app-video-pravachan-list",
  templateUrl: "./video-pravachan-list.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["./video-pravachan-list.page.scss"],
})
export class VideoPravachanListPage implements OnInit {
  constructor(
     public isFirstWindowOpen:Boolean,
     public isSecondWindowOpen:Boolean,
     public isThirdWindowOpen:Boolean,
     public menu: MenuController,
   ) {}...
```

**tab1.page.module.ts**

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    AudioListingPageRoutingModule,
   ],
   declarations: [AudioListingPage],
   providers: [{ provide: Boolean }, { provide: Array }],
```

Comment: the code runs perfectly on andriod but when building app for ios this error occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You shouldn't declare variables in the constructor.
2. Use lowercase boolean as it is the primitive type to type a variable
3. Remove all the providers in tab1.page.module.ts as it is not necessary (or correct)

Learn more about Boolean vs boolean here: 
https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-boolean/

```js
export class VideoPravachanListPage implements OnInit {

isFirstWindowOpen: boolean;
isSecondWindowOpen: boolean;
isThirdWindowOpen: boolean;

  constructor(
     public menu: MenuController,
   ) {}...
```

**EDIT**

The same works for an array. You can start with an empty array to push values in like the example below:

```js
arrayOfObjects: object[] = []
```

Comment: does it work with Array too? thank you very much for the answer

Comment: Yes, you can declare and use them in your ts files

Comment: Happy to help ;)